# How to get all files name,size, type and date created from specified folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get all the files name,size,type and date created from specified folder using javascript or jquery.

i.e :

```
var path = "d://files";
```

Please check this  [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/naL9v/1/). In this demo user can select a folder and get all the files name from that folder. Instead of choosing folder how to fetch directly from a specified path.

Comment: You can do it, in the parallel universe.

Comment: you cant access files and folders with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `Javascript` doesn't have access to the filesystem. You can do that using `Node JS` filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Browser Javascript doesn't have access to user's file system.

Server Javascript (like node.js) [may access to server's file system](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).